# Ajax not detecting php strings from api url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mashape

Below api(s) are perfectly working, i am getting proper output from "plan-api.php"

PHP CODE(plan-api.php)

```
if ($_GET['result']):
$rslt = $_GET['result'];
$result = Unirest\Request::get("https://sphirelabs-mobile-number-portability-india-operator-v1.p.mashape.com/index.php?number=$rslt",
array(
"X-Mashape-Key" => "XXXXXXXXXX",
"Accept" => "application/json"
)
);

$optid= rawurlencode($result->body->Operator);
$cirid=rawurlencode($result->body->{'Telecom circle'});

endif;  


// Create a stream
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"X-Mashape-Key: XXXXXXXXX"               
 )
 );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$requestUrl = "https://tariff-plan-api-datayuge.p.mashape.com/index.php?circleid=$cirid&limit=50&operatorid=$optid&recharge_type=3g";
$response = (file_get_contents($requestUrl, false, $context));

$data = json_decode($response, true);

$data2= json_encode($data);

echo $data2;
```

OUTPUT (from plan-api.php)

```
{"data":[{"id":"4401","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"60","recharge_talktime":"60","recharge_validity":"NA ","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 60 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Full Talktime ","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"},{"id":"4407","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"110","recharge_talktime":"110","recharge_validity":"Lifetime Validity","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 110 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Full Talktime ","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"},{"id":"4409","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"150","recharge_talktime":"150","recharge_validity":"Lifetime Validity","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 150 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Full Talktime ","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"},{"id":"4414","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"555","recharge_talktime":"600","recharge_validity":"Lifetime Validity","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 555 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Extra Talktime","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"}]}
```

HTML/AJAX(plan-ajax.php)

Here i am getting output in textbox if i put the value of `circleid` and `operatorid` but when i am trying to put the php objects output  of first api `$optid$cirid;` than i am not getting output in below textboxes.

I tried to add `$('#opt'+key).val(value.operator);` with textbox id "opt" but same no output

```
Please enter a Mobile number
<input type="text" id="search">
<br>


<input type="text" id="result0">
<input type="text" id="result1">
<input type="text" id="result2">
<input type="text" id="result3">
<br>
<input type="text" id="talk0">
<input type="text" id="talk1"> 
<input type="text" id="talk2">
<input type="text" id="talk3">


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search').keypress(function(){
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "plan-api.php",
        data: 'result=' + $('#search').val(),
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(responseText){

            $.each(responseText.data, function(key,value){

    $('#result'+key).val(value.recharge_amount);
       $('#talk'+key).val(value.recharge_talktime);

            });
        }

    }); // Ajax Call
}); //event handler

}); //document.ready
</script>
```

Comment: var_dump of `$response` from api would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Output from API is incorrect, it must be as following. Basically, it's not in JSON format.

```
{"data":[{"id":"4401","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar   Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"60","recharge_talktime":"60","recharge_validity":"NA ","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 60 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Full Talktime ","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"},{"id":"4407","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"110","recharge_talktime":"110","recharge_validity":"Lifetime Validity","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 110 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Full Talktime ","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"},{"id":"4409","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"150","recharge_talktime":"150","recharge_validity":"Lifetime Validity","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 150 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Full Talktime ","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"},{"id":"4414","operatorid":"Reliance GSM","circleid":"Bihar Jharkhand","recharge_amount":"555","recharge_talktime":"600","recharge_validity":"Lifetime Validity","recharge_shortdesc":"Recharge of Rs 555 By Reliance GSM","recharge_longdesc":"Extra Talktime","recharge_type":"Full Talktime"}]}
```

in `success:` of ajax you can put `console.log(responseText)` for clarity.

Remove the following from `plan-api.php`:

```
echo $optid;
echo $cirid;
```

Comment: `Reliance%20GSMBihar%20Jharkhand` this is the output from first api

Comment: @user3588059 Okay. Then remove `echo $optid;
echo $cirid;` from plan-api.php. I am assuming that is your actual code.